# How to flip Seq[Free[Functor, A]] to Free[Functor, Seq[A]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I am learning scalaz Free monad. I wonder how to can I get `Seq[Free[Functor, A]]` to `Free[Functor, Seq[A]]` similar like Future.sequence

Here is the code

```
  type Functor[A] = Coyoneda[Command, A]
  type Script[A]= Free[Functor, A]

  case instruction(...)

  def sequence(): Seq[Script[Instruction]] = {...}
```

I wonder that is that possible that I can flip the result to  `Script[Seq[Instruction]]` If it can be like Future does, Is that the reason Free is a monad ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `sequence` operation for `F[G[A]]` (e.g. `Seq[Script[Instruction]]`) whenever there are `Traverse[F]` and `Applicative[G]` instances. You do have the `Applicative[Script]` instance (`Script` is a `Monad`, so it is also `Applicative`), but `scalaz` does not provide a `Traverse` instance for `Seq`. (Immutable `Seq` is in principle traversable, but the authors chose not to provide `Traverse[Seq]` instance, presumably because `Seq` is abstract and hence scalaz cannot guarantee to give you back the same `Seq` implementation.)

I will therefore answer for `List` instead of `Seq`.

```
import scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

val scripts: List[Script[A]] = ???
val script: Script[List[A]] = scripts.sequence[Script, A]
```

Answer (score 0):

Free.freeMonad#sequence will help you flip the type constructors in both Cats and Scalaz. Alternative require the monad instance via implicit evidence and use the compiler injected implicit instance instead.